# :not(:last-child) css selector not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have these social media icons and I wanna apply a margin to every icon except for the last one, the problem is that when I use the **:not(:last-child)** it is not working, it is not doing anything.
Here is the HTML and CSS code:

```html
        <div class="icons">
          <a href="#"><img class="social-media-icon" src="../images/icon-facebook.svg" alt=""></a>
          <a href="#"><img class="social-media-icon" src="../images/icon-instagram.svg" alt=""></a>
          <a href="#"><img class="social-media-icon" src="../images/icon-pinterest.svg" alt=""></a>
          <a href="#"><img class="social-media-icon" src="../images/icon-twitter.svg" alt=""></a>
          <a href="#"><img class="social-media-icon" src="../images/icon-youtube.svg" alt=""></a>
        </div>
```

```css
 .social-media-icon:not(:last-child){
        margin-right:30px;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The nth-child selectors work on a direct children of their parent. So this should work:

```css
a:not(:last-child) .social-media-icon {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.icons {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
  <a href="#"><img class="social-media-icon" src="https://picsum.photos/50" alt=""></a>
  <a href="#"><img class="social-media-icon" src="https://picsum.photos/50" alt=""></a>
  <a href="#"><img class="social-media-icon" src="https://picsum.photos/50" alt=""></a>
  <a href="#"><img class="social-media-icon" src="https://picsum.photos/50" alt=""></a>
  <a href="#"><img class="social-media-icon" src="https://picsum.photos/50" alt=""></a>
</div>
```